# Вики разметка вконтакте

Tags: xhtml, html, вконтакте

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно достать wiki-разметку для группы вместе с psd.

Comment: Вот прикольное меню в стиле Ajax окон. [тут][1]. Также есть менюшки на офф группе. И советовал бы я вам просто научиться работать в ФШ.

  [1]: http://depositfiles.com/ru/files/g9ilxr67k

Comment: А почему не на летитбит сразу?

Answer (score 1):

У контакта есть оффициальная группа по разметке, там очень легко и доходчиво расписанно и люди выкладывают исходники свои, я просто брал примерял и всё

[Вот собственно и эта группа](http://vkontakte.ru/vrazmetke)

Answer (score 0):

Есть довольно интересный сервис: [учебник по вики разметке вконтакте](http://volonte.ru/2009/07/02/%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-wiki-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-vkontakte/).